# PingAccess - ASP.NET MVC 5 - .Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pingaccess

I have issue where the request headers from PingAccess are only populated about 10% of the time when I attempt to load those values within the `Session_Start` method in the `global.asax.cs` file.

I use the `HttpContext.Current` and then check the request headers for the values I need to authenticate the user session.

Any idea why the header values would only get returned to the session start on occasion?